JpaRepository Query with if conditions
I want to call Query in Kotlin with 2 IF conditions(if field exists add new filter else do nothing), but I do not know how to write it correctly. The problem is transactionsDateFrom and transactionsDateTo are unresolved variables.
    @Query("SELECT cla.* " +
        "FROM cla " +
        "LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = cla.user_c_id " +
        "LEFT JOIN transactions ON " +
        "transactions.user_id = cla.user_id " +
        "AND transactions.user_p_id = cla.user_c_id " +
        "AND transactions.created_at >= cla.sub_start_date " +
        "AND (transactions.status ILIKE 'done' OR transactions.status ILIKE 'loading') " +
        "${:transactionsDateFrom != null ? "AND t.created_at >= " :transactionsDateFrom : "" }" +
        "${:transactionsDateTo != null ? "AND t.created_at <= " :transactionsDateTo : ""}" +
        "WHERE cla.archived = false AND cla.sub_start_date <= :dateNow"
)
fun getClaInfo(transactionsDateFrom: LocalDateTime, transactionsDateTo: LocalDateTime,  dateNow: LocalDateTime): Entity  {}

